# What does int, jit, fast, and portable mean in build.prop's dalvik.vm.execution-mode?

Tags: dalvik, build.prop

There are many build.prop tweaks on the internet, and some says `dalvik.vm.execution-mode` should be `int:jit`, and some says it should be `fast:jit` or even in a reversed order as `jit:fast` for performance. What is the difference between `int` and `fast`, and does the order matter (before and after the colon)? My phone is running Android 4.4.2 KitKat.

Edit: Just a note, ART is not supported in my device (Samsung Galaxy Note 2), even if I install the dex2oat program and libart.so, it won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Summary

These are the values for Dalvik VM runtime:

- fast: optimized for the current platform, and might consist of hand-optimized assembly routines (default)
- portable: written in C and expected to run on a broad range of platforms
- jit: [just-in-time compilation](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2010/05/dalvik-jit.html)

As for the order, [the base source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/jni/AndroidRuntime.cpp#779) only recognizes `int:<mode>`.

---

According to [dalvik/docs/embedded-vm-control.html](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/lollipop-release/docs/embedded-vm-control.html#161),

> ### Execution Mode
>
> The current implementation of the Dalvik VM includes three distinct interpreter cores. These are referred to as "fast", "portable", and "debug". The "fast" interpreter is optimized for the current platform, and might consist of hand-optimized assembly routines. In constrast, the "portable" interpreter is written in C and expected to run on a broad range of platforms. The "debug" interpreter is a variant of "portable" that includes support for profiling and single-stepping.
>
> The VM may also support just-in-time compilation. While not strictly a different interpreter, the JIT compiler may be enabled or disabled with the same flag. (Check the output of `dalvikvm -help` to see if JIT compilation is enabled in your VM.)
>
> The VM allows you to choose between "fast", "portable", and "jit" with an extended form of the `-Xint` argument. The value of this argument can be set through the `dalvik.vm.execution-mode` system property.
>
> To select the "portable" interpreter, you would use:
>
> ```
> adb shell setprop dalvik.vm.execution-mode int:portable
> ```
>
> If the property is not specified, the most appropriate interpreter will be selected automatically. At some point this mechanism may allow selection of other modes, such as JIT compilation.
> Not all platforms have an optimized implementation. In such cases, the "fast" interpreter is generated as a series of C stubs, and the result will be slower than the "portable" version. (When we have optimized versions for all popular architectures the naming convention will be more accurate.)
>
> If profiling is enabled or a debugger is attached, the VM switches to the "debug" interpreter. When profiling ends or the debugger disconnects, the original interpreter is resumed. (The "debug" interpreter is substantially slower, something to keep in mind when evaluating profiling data.)
>
> The JIT compiler can be disabled on a per-application basis by adding `android:vmSafeMode="true"` in the application tag in `AndroidManifest.xml`. This can be useful if you suspect that JIT compilation is causing your application to behave incorrectly.

Also, according to [dalvik/docs/porting-guide.html](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/lollipop-release/docs/porting-guide.html#82),

> ### Interpreter
>
> The Dalvik runtime includes two interpreters, labeled "portable" and "fast".
> The portable interpreter is largely contained within a single C function,
> and should compile on any system that supports gcc.  (If you don't have gcc,
> you may need to disable the "threaded" execution model, which relies on
> gcc's "goto table" implementation; look for the THREADED_INTERP define.)
>
> The fast interpreter uses hand-coded assembly fragments.  If none are
> available for the current architecture, the build system will create an
> interpreter out of C "stubs".  The resulting "all stubs" interpreter is
> quite a bit slower than the portable interpreter, making "fast" something
> of a misnomer.
>
> The fast interpreter is enabled by default.  On platforms without native
> support, you may want to switch to the portable interpreter.  This can
> be controlled with the `dalvik.vm.execution-mode` system
> property.  For example, if you:
>
> ```
> adb shell "echo dalvik.vm.execution-mode = int:portable >> /data/local.prop"
> ```
>
> and reboot, the Android app framework will start the VM with the portable
> interpreter enabled.

---

Additional reading:

- [mobileread - Performance Boost: Enabling Dalvik's JIT compiler and increasing heap size)](https://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=234339)